# SwitchCompat setOnCheckedChangeListener() is not working in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i am using SwitchCompat to enable and disable functionality. I am using setOnCheckedChangeListener() to enable and disable functionality For this I am using `isChecked` to check whether switch is enabled or disabled. Condition works fine but in my condition it never falls on else condition.

code:-

```java
listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {            
    @Override                                                                                                    
    public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {                     
        if (isChecked) {                                                                                         
            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
            .setTitle("Warning").setMessage("").setPositiveButton("Ok",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override                                                                                        
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                         
                    //Adding items in Dataset                                                                    
                    AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);                                              
                    whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());                                                   
                    whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());                                           
                                                                                                                 
                    existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);                                                         
                    saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);                                            
                                                                                                                 
                    //Notifying adapter data has been changed.....                                               
                                                                                                                 
                    notifyDataSetChanged();                                                                      
                    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);                                               
                }                                                                                                
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                                   
                @Override                                                                                        
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                         
                    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);                                               
                }                                                                                                
            }).show();                                                                                           
                                                                                                                 
        } else {                                                                                                 
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                       
             existingDataSet.remove(position);                                                                   
             saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);                                                   
             notifyDataSetChanged();                                                                             
        }                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                 
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the issue is you made isCheck variable final and the final variable initialize once and its value not going to change again so remove final and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwitchCompat button is not working in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274385/switchcompat-button-is-not-working-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

make the changes.
 1.use the line

```
 listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
```

instead of

```
  listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
```

2. in the else part also, you have missed to set the status of button
   so add the line in else part.

   listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);

Comment: what about }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
                        }
                    }).show();