# SwitchCompat button is not working in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview which contain SwitchCompat button when i enable button on index 1 in listview and again when i enable button at position 2 it is disabling button at position 1. Pls help me out i don't understand what is happening.

code:-

```
 layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listStorage = customizedListView;
    this.mContext = context;
    existingDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    newDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    gson = new Gson();
    sharedPreference = new MySharedPreference(mContext);

    //retrieve data from shared preference
    String jsonScore = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
    }.getType();
    existingDataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonScore, type);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list_item, parent, false);
        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    boolean isCheck = false;
    AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
    if (existingDataSet != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
            if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                isCheck = true;
            }
        }
        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isCheck);
    }
    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                        //Adding items in Dataset
                        AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                        whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                        whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());

                        if (existingDataSet != null) {
                            existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                        } else {
                            newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
                    }
                }).show();

            } else {
                AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
                if (existingDataSet != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
                        if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                            existingDataSet.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }


    });
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * Save list of scores to own sharedpref
 *
 * @param whiteListApps
 */
private void saveScoreListToSharedpreference(ArrayList<WhiteListModel> whiteListApps) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //convert ArrayList object to String by Gson
    String jsonScore = gson.toJson(whiteListApps);
    Log.e(TAG, "LIST::" + jsonScore);
    //save to shared preference
    sharedPreference.saveAppsArrayListData(jsonScore);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    SwitchCompat switchCompat;
    TextView textInListView;
    ImageView imageInListView;
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your full adapter code, it will help to understand your problem

Comment: see my full adapter code....................

Comment: try not use two data sets , instead modify the original dataset and call notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect the changes in adapter

Comment: or rather than doing that keep a bean of data in that keep a boolean which will be having the state of switch. on change simply change that variable.
i.e. your list `listStorage` bean add that boolean to this, and on view created check if boolean is true or false, if it is true switch on your switch else switch it off, if not able to understand this, i will put the code for you

Comment: put the code for me....

Answer (score 0):

**boolean isCheck = false;** use This thing by an array and make checked and unchecked at that particular position.

Like below;-

**boolean isChecked[];
isChecked[position]=true;**